# How to pass value to foreign key

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have two tables users and orders

Table 1: users

```
users_id primary & auto increment
users_name 
users_surname
```

Table 2: orders

```
orders_id primary & auto increment
orders_users_id foreign key
order_name
```

How do I pass the users_id to orders_users_id?

How can I make to connection between to that every time a users order the order_users id would be equal to that?

Comment: This is called a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

use mysql `inner join` :-

```
select * from orders inner join 
users on orders.orders_users_id=users.users_id
```